# JS && precedence vs ===

Tags: javascript, node.js, operators

According to javascript [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the `===` operator is higher precedence than `&&` operator.  Therefore, I would expect an expression like

`false && undefined.foo() === undefined.foo()`

to throw an error while evaluating either one of `undefined.foo()` calls.  However, as I've tried in node, chrome, and firefox, the js engine always short circuits and returns `false` e.g.

```
> false && undefined.foo() === undefined.foo()
false
```

Shouldn't `&&` short circuit kick in **after** `===` operands have been evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The higher precedence merely means that both operands `undefined.foo()` are associated with the `===` operator first before the operands for `&&` are decided. It does not dictate the **order of execution**, which is still left to right.

Operator precedence merely decides whether the expression is evaluated as

```
(false && undefined.foo()) === undefined.foo()
```

or

```
false && (undefined.foo() === undefined.foo())
```

In either case `false` is still the first thing that's being evaluated; though if `&&` had the higher precedence (first parenthesised example) then the 2nd `undefined` expression *would* always be evaluated too.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

To better visualize why the precedence is being parsed the way it is, add in optional parenthesis according to how the interpreter ranks precedence:

`( (false) && ( undefined.foo() === undefined.foo() ) )`

Because `===` has higher precedence than `&&`, parenthesis gets added around the `undefined.foo() === undefined.foo()` expression first. Since precedence has now been determined, JavaScript interpreters will now parse it from left to right. Due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the `undefined.foo()` comparison expression never gets evaluated since the condition exits upon evaluating the `false`

Comment: I think its short circuit instead of lazy evaluation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908548/any-difference-between-lazy-evaluation-and-short-circuit-evaluation

Comment: I always thought it was just called lazy evaluation overall. But I see now that it's "short circuit" because it exits early. But it also never evaluates the remaining expressions until needed, making it lazy. It seems lazy & short circuit have a very fine, grey line between them.

Comment: Lazy evaluation has a very specific meaning, and Javascript actually supports no such thing. Think of a `map` operation over an *infinite* list (or just an infinite list by itself); this is only possible through lazy evaluation, which will defer the actual evaluation until the result is actually needed (pseudo example: `print(infList.map(foo)[0])`), otherwise the `map` would never finish.

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Control_structures section focuses more on the bodies of control structures, but says "Short-circuit evaluation of Boolean control structures is sometimes called lazy". Whereas, the short-circuit wiki applies specifically to the evaluation of the actual parameters. Seems I was taught wrong! Updated my answer. Thank you for drawing attention to this.