# How can I construct an array of unique objects?

Tags: python, oop

Within my code, I need to create an array of a user-specified magnitude. Usually, the code I'd use for this is:

```
array = [[x] * a for b in range(size)]
```

In the above examples, the variables are as follows:

x -> item in the array spaces

a -> width

b -> height

However, I used this code to try and make the array house objects as follows:

```
gameboard = [[Cell(screen_size, size)] * size for size in range(size)]
```

In this case, x is my object "Cell" with the variables that need to be passed in for it, and a / b are both size, as the array is to be square. The issue I'm facing is the top row forms correctly where new objects are created. However, the following rows are just repeats of the top row, not new objects as they should be.

For example, if size was 5, I want a 5x5 of 25 different cell objects. However, instead I get a 5x5 where the top layer is unique objects. However, the rest are only copies, and therefore I have five unique objects with five references each, rather than 25 unique objects.

Comment: I recommend naming your variables such that they explain themselves:
`array = [[x] * width for height in range(size)]`

Comment: `b` is not the height, it's the row index.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think it has to do with the `*` operator, but which objects are being 'multiplied` You can safely created a list of identical integers that way, without running into this issue.

Comment: @IzaakCornelis no, that is absolutely incorrect. It is how the `*` operator always works. `int` objects expose no mutator methods, so not creating copies of the objects (i.e. new objects with different identities) doesn't matter with `int` objects, but semantics of `*` works precisely the same way it always does

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The behavior of (in the sense of what this post is about)  `[object] * int` is depends on the object, as shown in my example of creating a list of identical integers.

Comment: @IzaakCornelis **no it absolutely does not change the bahvior at all**. Using integers `[3]*3` behaves exactly thes ame way as `[[]]*3`, both result in a list with *three refencees to the object*, in the first case, that object is an `int`. In the second case, that object is a `list`. The operator worked **exactly the same**

Comment: @IzaakCornelis Here, I'll prove it to you. `data = [1337]*10; import ctypes; ctypes.cast(id(data[0]), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))[6] = 9999; print(data)` "immutable' simply means "does not expose mutator methods', we can use our knowledge of implementation details to mutate an `int` object. And you will see, you get the exact same behavior when you do

Comment: Ah so when trying to modify an int you create a new instance of int? I'm sorry if I upset you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly call the instructor to create new objects of a certain class. The expression `[Cell(screen_size, size)] * size` does not do this, it creates a copy of the list `[Cell(screen_size, size)]` `size` times.

A fix could be a nested list comprehension statement:

```
gameboard = [[Cell(screen_size, size) for _ in range(size)] for size in range(size)]
```

This not only calls the `Cell` constructor for each row, but for each element in the row as well.

Comment: `for size in range(size)` does not seem correct. It will result in a triangular array.

Comment: python does not have lazy evaluation

Comment: @interjay There is some shadowing going on I agree, size in the for loop shadows the outer variable size

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It most certainly does. However in this case I did not mean lazy evaluation. It's lazy in that python does not create new objects, it just copies the references.

Comment: @IzaakCornelis no, it most certainly does not (unless you are referring to generators). Expressions are evaluated eagerly,in any case, if that isn't what you mean, then. I might suggest changing the wording then, size "lazy" has a particular meaning that would come to mind

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I count generators as lazy, if you don't think that counts, try this if statement: `if False and 1/0: ...` This will not raise a divide by zero exception as the second expression is never evaluated.

Comment: @IzaakCornelis See [Any difference between Lazy evaluation and Short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908548/any-difference-between-lazy-evaluation-and-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not know about the distinction, but I fail to see why generators are not lazy evaluation. I'll edit my post to change the wording and make it easier to understand.